# Want sip response code(like 100, 180, 200..) from Asterisk Manager Interface(AMI)

Tags: asterisk, asteriskami

Goal is to get SIP response codes(like 100, 180, 200..) from asterisk manager interface:

What I have done:

-create new user in manager.conf in /etc/asterisk

-for getting the sip messages, connected to default port 5038 using telnet and by using 'Login' action with appropriate username, password
details successfully connects to asterisk manager interface

But in these bulk of details I am not getting actual sip response codes, i want to monitor them.

-I read different actions synopsis from asterisk cli by firing 'manager show commands' but not able to get clear idea of which action 
would be useful.

How can i get those resoponse codes? Any thought would be helpful on this one.

Thanks.

Edit: Got this link while mining, http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Manager+API+Action+ExtensionState
this is good, but i want exact sip response code

Answer (score 1):

There are no any code like that in chan_sip.c

You are welcome to add more events inside that file and rebuild asterisk.

However if you expect low-level control over sip messages, asterisk is bad choice. Use opensips or kamailio projects.